# Чрезмерно большой размер процесса java

Tags: java, ibm

На windows имеется сервер приложений ibm на java 1.8.0.311 версии (IBM J9 VM).
Выставлены параметры максимального размера кучи 3гб. Согласно jconsole текущий размер кучи около 1,5гб. Дополнительно согласно jconsole загруженные классы и прочее занимает около 1гб в сумме.

Но при этом java процесс вырос (не в первый раз) более чем до 8гб в памяти.

Как такое возможно? В чём может быть проблема? Что случилось с около 5 гигабайтами памяти? И что можно сделать?